# Do a while in a query, subquery

Tags: mysql

I want do query that show data of some users bat, first is a other query, is something difficult of explain. i dont want get the data of the users that me follow, i want see data that me don't follow. So i have two table "follow_follower", "user" and now do a middle query but doesn't match:

```
follow_follower

cod     seguidor    seguido
1       1           2
2       1           3
3       1           8
4       1           6
5       8           2
6       2           8
7       2           4
8       3           2
9       5           1

User

cod nombre      apellido    telefono
1   carlos      cardenas    12587
2   Umberto     Contreras   125488
3   carlos      Torres      44587
4   Victor      Sambrano    69754
5   Carlos      Barragan    3698741
6   Jorge       Cantor      
7   Umberto     Zanetty     578825
8   Miguel      Cantor      5488787
```

ok and if you see are four fields in follow_follower that the user is 1 (Carlos Cardenas), how do query that first get all user that me follow and after select all data of people diferent "DISTICN" see my query:

```
select distinct(nombre), apellido, telefono
    FROM usuario
    where cod<> ANY(select seguido from follow_follower where seguidor=1)
    order by cod
```

But only DISTINC a ANY row of all query.

---

ok i want a list little of people that me don't follow but i see your query and show error, i know little of mysql query ADVANCE :( and the other problem is that my db is write in spanish... but go to try the table db like are!!!  :

this is a the true query:

```
SELECT distinct(usua.cod), usua.nick, desi.usuario, main.dir, main.size, main.x, main.y,   main.R, main.G, main.B, main.A
FROM usuario AS usua, design AS desi, mainPhoto AS main
WHERE desi.usuario = usua.cod
AND desi.cod = main.design
AND usua.cod <> ANY(select seguido from seguidor_seguido where seguidor=1)/**!!!!!/
AND main.dir <>  ''
AND main.type =1
ORDER BY usua.nick DESC
LIMIT 44 , 6
```

so the unique table that true import are usuario (content data of user) and seguidor_seguido(content all the records follow)

---describe table seguidor_seguido:

```
seguidor_seguido
cod // is the id of the record
seguidor  // is the user that follow to other users
seguido   // is the user that is followed by other users
```

Although the request is different from the original is the same problem!!!
thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally end the query and match ok!!  :D see:

```
SELECT U.cod, U.nombre, U.apellido, U.telefono FROM User U LEFT JOIN (SELECT f.seguido
FROM follow_follower f
WHERE f.seguidor = 1)t1 ON u.cod = t1.seguido
WHERE t1.seguido IS NULL AND U.cod <> 1 GROUP BY U.cod
```

this is the query that me need, but i thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a list of all users that don't follow you. I'm not sure if you want that to be transitive or not (i.e., including users that follow users that follow you, etc.).

If you just want to do it one level deep, it'll go like this. You want to get a list of all entries in the `follow_follower` where the `seguido` (I assume that's supposed to mean "person who is being followed") is not you. Users can follow other people, but they can't follow you. You can join twice against the `User` table to get user names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       usuario_seguidor.nombre,
       usuario_seguidor.applido,
       usuario_seguidor.telephono
  FROM follow_follower
  JOIN usuario AS usuario_seguidor
    ON usuario_seguidor.cod = follow_follower.seguidor
 WHERE follow_follower.seguido <> 1
```